# How to sort the matrix according to specific row?

Tags: matlab, sorting

I have a population generated by pop=[pop;x;y;z;cst,fr]; where first 4 rows are x, second 3 rows are y and third 8 rows are z. cst is sum of column 1 and fr is calculated failure rate of column 2.

```
        6        0.876
        5         0.99
        3        0.939
        6        0.876
        4        0.837
        7        0.959
        4        0.953
        4        0.873
        0            0
        5         0.95
        3        0.855
        4        0.873
        4        0.873
        5         0.95
        6        0.951
       66   0.00032352            
        6        0.876
        6        0.876
        6        0.965
        6        0.965
        4        0.953
        4        0.837
        4        0.953
        0            0
        3        0.855
        6        0.951
        5         0.95
        0            0
        0            0
        3        0.855
        6        0.951
       59   0.00038143
        6        0.965
        5        0.888
        6        0.965
        3        0.863
        7        0.889
        7        0.959
        4        0.953
        7        0.915
        6        0.968
        3        0.855
        3        0.855
        8        0.942
        4        0.873
        3        0.855
        8        0.942
       80    0.0002327
```

How can I sort the specific (16,32,48) rows followed by unchanged (1:15,17:31,33:47)? 
for example:

```
        6        0.876
        6        0.876
        6        0.965
        6        0.965
        4        0.953
        4        0.837
        4        0.953
        0            0
        3        0.855
        6        0.951
        5         0.95
        0            0
        0            0
        3        0.855
        6        0.951
       59   0.00038143
        6        0.876
        5         0.99
        3        0.939
        6        0.876
        4        0.837
        7        0.959
        4        0.953
        4        0.873
        0            0
        5         0.95
        3        0.855
        4        0.873
        4        0.873
        5         0.95
        6        0.951
       66   0.00032352
        6        0.965
        5        0.888
        6        0.965
        3        0.863
        7        0.889
        7        0.959
        4        0.953
        7        0.915
        6        0.968
        3        0.855
        3        0.855
        8        0.942
        4        0.873
        3        0.855
        8        0.942
       80    0.0002327
```

Please help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. I think you should identify the language you are using (is it R?) that supports `pop=[pop;x;y;z;cst,fr]`.  Your sorting criterion is not clearly expressed yet. As far as I can tell, you want groups of 16 lines (where the sixteenth lines in the examples has a larger value in column 1) sorted on the key number, which is the first value in the sixteenth row.  Which tools are available for use (`awk`, `perl`, ...) and which platform are you using? How big are the files?

Comment: Hi, I am using Matlab. pop is the population size.It loops for 3 times and gives me 3x15 (x:3rows, y:4rows and z:8rows) where 16th row is sum of column 1. I wanted to sort like this, For example:

From:

  a

  b

  2ab

  c

  d

  1cd

  e

  f

  3ef
To:

  c

  d

  1cd

  a

  b

  2ab

  e

  f

  3ef
Hope I explained it correctly.

Comment: Include that tag 'matlab' on the question; that will get it to the attention of people who know Matlab.  I've done that for you this time, but in future, it helps a lot to direct the question to the right audience.  I know nothing about Matlab and can't help you further on this.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear exactly what order you want, but if you know you want some specific row ordering like this: (16,32,48) rows followed by unchanged (1:15,17:31,33:47) then you can use indexing just like this:

```
n = [16, 32, 48, 1:15, 17:31, 33:47]; % indexes for sorting
popsort = pop(n,:); %index into pop by rows
```

There are various tricks you could use to create the index vector `n`.

Now, if you are calling a loop and appending new values to `pop` like this:

```
pop = []
for n = 1:3
    % calculate x, y, z, etc.
    pop=[pop;x;y;z;cst,fr];
end
```

Then it may be better to pre-allocate the matrix `pop` and put your values where you want them in the first place, or use two variables, one containing your `x,y,z` and the other with the `cst,fr` values in.  That would avoid the need to sort the rows afterwards:

```
m = 3; % works for any number of loops
pop = zeros(m*15,2);
cst_fr = zeros(m,2);
for n = 0:m-1
    % calculate x, y, z, etc.
    pop(1+n*15:15+n*15,:)=[x;y;z];
    cst_fr(n+1,:)=[cst,fr];
end
```